# error: (-215) count >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function arcLength

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using python 2.7

I'm getting this error when i try to run the epsilon operation on it,
this is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img.jpeg')
img = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img)
epsilon = 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(img, True)
approx  = cv2.approxPolyDP(img, epsilon, True)
hull = cv2.convexHull(img)
```

This is the Error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/decentmakeover2/lanedetect.py", line 6, in <module>
    epsilon = 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(img, True)
error: /home/decentmakeover2/opencv-
3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:285: error: (-215) count >= 0 && 
(depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function arcLength
```

Im not sure what to change here,any ideas?

Edit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/decentmakeover2/lanedetect.py", line 8, in <module>
    epsilon = 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(img,True)
TypeError: curve data type = 6 is not supported
>>>
```

[image]

Comment: The Python boolean or operator is `or`, not `||`.

Comment: But i don't have `or`  in my code,Am i misiing something here?

Comment: The error here is saying that `count` is not `>=0` which means that `checkVector(2)` failed on your `Mat`, or that the dtype is not 32-bit float or int which means that it's not the correct bit-depth. You can check the source code here:https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/fee87ea3f752038ef303f37b72a46633ae236968/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp#L277. What is the colour depth of your jpeg? You need to convert it to 32-bit float/int in order for `arclength` to be happy

Comment: @DanielRoseman that error is being thrown from openCV in the `c++` code so it's not relevant to the op's problem. The issue here is that the array is either the incorrect shape and/or type

Comment: @EdChum ,i converted it to 32 bit, now i get `TypeError: curve data type = 6 is not supported`, any ideas?

Comment: Please post the full error traceback into your question rather than in the comments, also can you upload your actual jpeg?

Comment: Sure, its posted

Comment: You must use arcLength with an array of points, not an image. How can you possibly compute the arc length of an image?

Comment: @Miki Sorry for the stupid question ,im trying out some code from a textbook, so i thought the error was due to something else.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`arcLength`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8d26483c636be6b35c3ec6335798a47c) (and also `approxPolyDP` and `convexHull`) needs as input an

> Input vector of 2D points

and not an image.

All these functions works on points, it doesn't make sense to compute the *length of the arc* (or the *polygonal approximation*, or the *convex hull*) for an image.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this error when I tried to generate the convex Hull of groups of 2D points.
The error message looks like this:

*cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\convhull.cpp:137: error: (-215:Assertion failed) total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'cv::convexHull'*

The reason turned out to be that my input points were float number instead of integer. So I use *numpy.astype(np.int)* to change the input points' data type.